How to use in TSX Enum values defined with Object.freeze
I need a key/value Enum in JS and am following this example:
const DaysOfWeek = Object.freeze({
        SUNDAY: "str1",
        MONDAY: "str2"
    });

Now, I have a component whose prop needs to be one of the Enum-defined values, and nothing else.
I can't do
 const MyComp = (props: { dayOfWeek: DaysOfWeek }) => { 
 }

 'DaysOfWeek' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof DaysOfWeek'?

Obviously I don't want to pass in the typeof DaysOfWeek itself as the prop, since I'm not using the Enum as a whole.
If I do
const MyComp = (props: { dayOfWeek: string }) => { 
   //... check dayOfWeek
   if (dayOfWeek === DaysOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
      //...
   }
.. 
}

this doesn't strongly check that dayOfWeek comes exclusively from the Enum. I have to limit it to the values of the Enum.
So what should I do?

The type of the values ("str1" | "str2") is typeof DaysOfWeek[keyof typeof DaysOfWeek]. Also FYI geeksforgeeks tends to be pretty bad and TypeScript has enums.
